# active_admin logout link not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, activeadmin

I have devise installed on my "core" engine. The logout link is: `core.destroy_user_session_path`

I just installed active_admin. Mostly working fine, except the logout link. In the config file, I found the following:

```
  # == Logging Out
  #
  # Active Admin displays a logout link on each screen. These
  # settings configure the location and method used for the link.
  #
  # This setting changes the path where the link points to. If it's
  # a string, the strings is used as the path. If it's a Symbol, we
  # will call the method to return the path.
  #
  # Default:
  config.logout_link_path = "core.destroy_user_session_path".to_sym
  # config.logout_link_path = "/core/users/sign_out" --> this works!

  # This setting changes the http method used when rendering the
  # link. For example :get, :delete, :put, etc..
  #
  # Default:
   config.logout_link_method = :delete
```

The error message I get is:

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `core.destroy_user_session_path' for #<ActiveAdmin::Views::TabbedNavigation:0x007f936dc8a8e0>:
  arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/element.rb:177:in `method_missing'
  /Users/krg07/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/active_admin-a9949c152420/lib/active_admin/view_helpers/method_or_proc_helper.rb:56:in `call_method_or_proc_on'
```

Any ideas? I have a feeling that it is calling the method within the "admin" namespace, and hence it can't find the method. If this is the case, how would I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: see the comment "# If it's a Symbol, we will call the method to return the path." as "main_app.destroy_user_session_path".to_sym is a Symbol the system is trying to call it, but since there is none the error is raised, does "main_app.destroy_user_session_path" solely work?

Comment: sorry, the code I put was slightly outdated. I have updated it. The line was "core.destroy_user_session_path".to_sym -

Comment: the to_sym converts it to a symbol. This was done so that active_admin didn't think it was a direct link ... but rather than a method. (I am trying to call the url helper methods

Comment: what is th result of config.logout_link_path = "core.destroy_user_session_path" line?? does it working fine?